# Laravel/Blade Form PUT Method, dd(Input::all());

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi I send a form in my contact.blade.php. I read in order to use the PUT method you have to create a hidden input field which contains the method.

```
      @if($do == 'edit')
        {{ Form::model($contact, array('method' => 'PUT', 'route' => array('contact.update', $contact->id), 'id' => $do=='edit' ? $do.$contact->id : $do.$contact_type_id, 'form_id' => $do=='edit' ? $do.$contact->id : $do.$contact_type_id)) }}
        {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') }}
      @endif
        ....
        {{ Form::submit('speichern', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
        </div>
      {{ Form::close() }}
```

The route:

```
Route::put('/contact/{id}', array(
    'uses'      => 'ContactController@update',
    'as'        => 'contact.update'
));
```

The Controller:

```
public function update($id)
{
    dd(Input::all());
    // //get user account data
    // $user = User::find( Auth::id() );
    // // validate input
    // $v = Contact::dataValidation( Input::all() );
    return Redirect::Route('user.edit', 1)->withSuccess("<em>Hans</em> wurde gespeichert.");
```

Q1:
As soon as I call `dd(Input::all());` I don't get redirected any more, instead I see a json with my form values.

Q2:
I'm just debugging this so I didn't program it. So my second question is:
From my understanding `dd(Input::all());` gets all my form data. So don't I need to store it anyways somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

**Q1**: dd() terminates the script, hence why you are not getting redirected. It's used as a tool to essentially break and examine what is going on.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers

**Q2**: You will still need a model to feed the `Input::all` data into. Input::all simply fetches the submitted data, it doesn't do anything with it. It ultimately depends on your use case, sometimes you may want to email the data, but obviously most times you would what to store it against your persistence layer (read database / datastore)

Comment: Removing it seemed to make the function work. Is there any reason/use why the former programmer could have added this? Or asekd the other way around, because it is not saved it was probably just to see the json?

Comment: If this is from a previous programmer, I would assume he was debugging to see what was happening

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**
when you use DD, it will show the data and stop at that line.

DD

> Dump the given variable and end execution of the script.

more information you can read it here [DD](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers) in DD session.

**Question 2**
I'am not sure about 2nd question but if you want to get value from all input you could us `Input::all();`
more information [All input](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests) in Getting All Input For The Request session